# Convert Postgis table to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, postgis

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just export to shapefile or kml and then reimport to SQL Server using one of [these standard tools](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools.aspx).  For example:

`SELECT  ST_AsKML(the_geom) FROM the_spatial_table WHERE ....`

This outputs kml, which you can then reimport to SQL Server (I assume, not SQL server guy, but it is a common format.)  [Here: http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.4/ch07.html#Geometry_Outputs](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.4/ch07.html#Geometry_Outputs) are the other geometry output formats for Postgis.